# Does a "...used out of scope." error in KSLint cause a '[1] is null or not an object' error?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to use JavaScript to populate a drop-down list and am getting the following error in IE8:

Message: '1' is null or not an object
Line: 59
Char: 3
Code: 0

When I push the code through a debugger (In this case, JSBin), I see the following error in the code:

Line 59: var $selected_view = $( '#ai1ec-view-' + matches[1] ); --- 'matches' used out of scope.

Would this error in JSBin correlate to the error in IE8?  When the code runs on Chrome, FF, or IE9, the error does not populate whatsoever.

Here is a snippet of the code in question.

```
// Make current view actively selected in view dropdown button.
    var classes = $('body').attr( 'class' ).split( ' ' );
    for ( i in classes ) {
        // Extract current view from the body class.
        var matches = /ai1ec-action-([\w]+)/.exec( classes[i] );
        if ( matches != null ) break;
    }
    // Get the dropdown menu link of the active view.
    var $selected_view = $( '#ai1ec-view-' + matches[1] );
    // Replace contents of dropdown button with menu link, plus the caret.
    $( '#ai1ec-current-view' )
        .contents()
            .remove()
            .end()
        .prepend( $selected_view.contents().clone() )
        .append( '<span class="caret"></span>' );
    // Deactivate all dropdown menu items.
    $( '#ai1ec-view-dropdown .dropdown-menu li' ).removeClass( 'active' );
    // Activate only currently selected dropdown menu item.
    $selected_view.parent().addClass( 'active' );
```

Comment: The JSBin warning seems bogus, Javascript does not have block scope, so the `matches` variable is actually scoped to the entire function, thus is in-scope at the line in question.

Answer (score 0):

No. The out-of-scope linter hint/error/message is probably because the variable was declared in the body-block of that for-in-loop; this should work.

Yet, `matches` seems to be `null` - causing the exception. You do break the loop as soon as `matches` is not null, but that does not guarantee that something really matched - the loop may just end, and `matches` is still null.

BTW: You should not use a for-in-loop to enumerate the properties of the array returned by `split`, you want to iterate the items with a normal for-loop.